# How to disable prettier in nest js

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm using Nest JS, but Prettier keeps bothering me with formatting errors while I'm trying to develop. It's frustrating because it distracts me from actual coding. How can I turn off Prettier just for now and then turn it on again when I want?

I tried removing format from the `package.json` file, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not related with nestjs itself.

Just remove the package using `npm uninstall prettier` and the configuration file `.prettierrc`, as any other nodejs library.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new NestJS project, the CLI will automatically generate a sample prettier configuration file named `.prettierrc` in the root of the project. do disable the rules, you can comment out every key from that object so it remains empty. that way prettier rules will not apply until you uncomment them

Answer (score 0):

To disable `prettier` in a `nestjs` project, open a file called `.eslintrc.js` .

It should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};
```

Comment out the plugin called `'plugin:prettier/recommended'` in the `extends` array.

Your updatted `.eslintrc.js` should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    // below plugin commented out because it was putting unwanted red squiggly lines in my code
    // 'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};
```